# Div 100% height inside Div is not working

Tags: html, css

I am designing a dashboard interface for myself. I am having some problems with inner divs, my leftpane div is set to 100% height inside the parent but it is overflowing parent div by the amount of 50px which is the height of topbar. Please suggest me why it is overflowing, 100% should mean whatever available space there is, isn't it?

here is my css and html

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: table;
}

.topbar {
 height: 50px;
 background: #353535;
 background-color: #353535;
 clear:both;
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
}

.leftpane {
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #eee;
 float: left;
 border-right: 2px solid #353535;
}

.content {
 width: 79%;
 height: 100%;
 float:right;
 border: 2px solid red;
}

.content-header {
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #353535;
 width: 100%;
}

.content-area {
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
 border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>GUYACOM - Suivi de la connectivit&eacute;</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" /> -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" /> -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinybox.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="topbar"><h1>
 </h1></div>
 <div class="content-area">
  <div class="leftpane">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="content-header">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One solution is to use `height: calc(100% - 50px)`, second to use `display: table/table-row/table-cell`, third to use `flexbox`, fourth JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may help you...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>GUYACOM - Suivi de la connectivit&eacute;</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
<style>
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
}

.topbar {
    height: 50px;
    background: #353535;
    background-color: #353535;
    clear:both;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}

.leftpane {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #353535;
}

.content {
    width: 79.5%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.content-header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #353535;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-area {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="topbar"><h1>
    </h1></div>
    <div class="content-area">
        <div class="leftpane">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working thank you so much :) Can I ask why it was not working without absolute position? 100% by defaults means it should take whatever available space is there right?

Comment: If you not give postion absolute, after topbar section only it will take 100%.  then the height will increase 100%+topbar height

Comment: Its not the correct way I think, it initially seem to be working but when I check it on developer tools, it infact has gone inside topbar and now my content-topbar is hidden inside it which is also 50px